# ExpandableListView siempre retorna 0 al contar los grupos

Tags: android, listview

Estoy listando bloques los cuales tienen actividades.
Todo funciona a la perfección, excepto que el contador de grupos no funciona, siempre retorna 0. Los datos los cargo desde un servidor externo con volley.

**Actividad mis bloques**

```
package cl.saval.emc.emc;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MyBlocksActivity extends BaseActivity
{
    private ExpandableListView listViewMyCoursesBlocks;
    private ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    private List<String> listDataHeader = new ArrayList<>();
    private HashMap<String,List<Activity>> listHash = new HashMap<>();
    private Course myCourse;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_blocks);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    myCourse = i.getExtras().getParcelable("myCourse");

    listViewMyCoursesBlocks = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewMyCoursesBlocks);

    //Init Data
    initData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),listDataHeader,listHash);
    listViewMyCoursesBlocks.setAdapter(listAdapter);


    //listViewMyCoursesBlocks.setGroupIndicator(null);

    //Solo un grupo, se muestran todas las actividades por defecto
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "size: " + listAdapter.getGroupCount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //-> here always show 0
    /*if( listAdapter.getGroupCount() == 1 ){
        //listViewMyCoursesBlocks.e;
    }*/

    listViewMyCoursesBlocks.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)
        {
            Activity myActivity = (Activity)parent.getExpandableListAdapter().getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
            if( myActivity.getIsBlocked() == 0 )
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyClassActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("myActivity", myActivity);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
            }
            return  false;
        };
    });
}
public void initData()
{
    //listDataHeader  = new ArrayList<>();
    //listHash = new HashMap<>();

    final String url   = Globals.APIACTIVIDADES_URL;
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.getInstance(this).getRequestQueue();
    StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response)
        {
            try
            {
                JSONObject JSONresponse = new JSONObject(response);
                if ( !JSONresponse.has("error") )
                {
                    int actividadesArr_length = 0;
                    int bloquesActividadesArr_length = 0;
                    int bloquesArr_length = 0;

                    if ( JSONresponse.has("actividades") && JSONresponse.get("actividades") instanceof JSONArray )
                    {
                        JSONArray actividadesArr = JSONresponse.getJSONArray("actividades");
                        actividadesArr_length = actividadesArr.length();

                        listDataHeader.add("BLOQUE I");

                        List<Activity> actividades = new ArrayList<>();

                        for (int i = 0; i < actividadesArr_length; i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject activity = new JSONObject(actividadesArr.getString(i));
                            Integer id   = activity.getInt("id");
                            String title = activity.getString("titulo");
                            String titlePref = activity.getString("tituloprefijo");
                            String teacher = activity.getString("expositores");
                            Integer isAccomplished = activity.getInt("cumplida");
                            Integer isBlocked = activity.getInt("bloqueo");
                            Integer hvVideo = activity.getInt("tienevideo");

                            actividades.add(new Activity(id, titlePref, title, teacher, isAccomplished, isBlocked, hvVideo));
                        }
                        listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(0),actividades);
                    }
                    if ( JSONresponse.has("bloques") && JSONresponse.get("bloques") instanceof JSONArray )
                    {
                        JSONArray bloquesArr = JSONresponse.getJSONArray("bloques");
                        bloquesArr_length = bloquesArr.length();

                        int ini = 0;
                        if( actividadesArr_length > 0 ){
                            ini = 1;
                        }

                        int romanNumber = 1;
                        for (int i = ini; i < bloquesArr_length; i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject bloque = new JSONObject(bloquesArr.getString(i));
                            String titulo_bloque  = bloque.getString("titulo");

                            listDataHeader.add("BLOQUE " + RomanNumerals.toRoman(romanNumber) + ": " + titulo_bloque);

                            List<Activity> actividades = new ArrayList<>();

                            if (bloque.has("actividades") && bloque.get("actividades") instanceof JSONArray)
                            {
                                JSONArray actividadesArr = bloque.getJSONArray("actividades");
                                bloquesActividadesArr_length = actividadesArr.length();

                                for (int j = 0; j < bloquesActividadesArr_length; j++)
                                {
                                    JSONObject activity = new JSONObject(actividadesArr.getString(j));

                                    Integer id   = activity.getInt("id");
                                    String title = activity.getString("titulo");
                                    String titlePref = activity.getString("tituloprefijo");
                                    String teacher = activity.getString("expositores");
                                    Integer isAccomplished = activity.getInt("cumplida");
                                    Integer isBlocked = activity.getInt("bloqueo");
                                    Integer hvVideo = activity.getInt("tienevideo");

                                    actividades.add(new Activity(id, titlePref, title, teacher, isAccomplished, isBlocked, hvVideo));
                                } //for actividades
                            }
                            romanNumber++;
                            listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(i),actividades);
                        } // for bloques
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "size: " + listAdapter.getGroupCount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //-> here always show correct value
                }
                else
                {
                    JSONObject error = JSONresponse.getJSONObject("error");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: [" + error.getString("num") + "] " + error.getString("msg"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error al recuperar sus datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
        {
            String message = "Error de conexión";
            if (!error.getMessage().isEmpty()) {
                message += ": [" + error.getMessage() + "]";
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            HashMap<String, String> user = sesion.getUserDetails();

            // get user data from session
            params.put("sesion", user.get(sesion.getKEY_CODE()));
            params.put("curso", myCourse.getId().toString());
            return checkParams(params);
        }
    };
    queue.add(req);
}
}
```

**Adaptador mis bloques**

```
package cl.saval.emc.emc;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by daniel on 16-02-17.
 * Modified by felipe on 2-02-17
*/

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
{
    private Context context;
    private List<String> listDataHeader;
    private HashMap<String,List<Activity>> listHashMap;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<Activity>> listHashMap)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this.listHashMap = listHashMap;
}
@Override
public int getGroupCount() { return listDataHeader.size(); }
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
    return listHashMap.get(listDataHeader.get(i)).size();
}
@Override
public Object getGroup(int i) {
    return listDataHeader.get(i);
}
@Override
public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
    return listHashMap.get(listDataHeader.get(i)).get(i1);
}
@Override
public long getGroupId(int i) {
    return i;
}
@Override
public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
    return i1;
}
@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}
@Override
public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
{
    String headerTitle = (String)getGroup(i);
    if(view == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listexpandable_group,null);
    }
    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
    return view;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int i, int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
{
    Activity activity = (Activity)getChild(i,i1);
    //Toast.makeText(this.context, "texto: " + childText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if(view == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listexpandable_item_row,null);
    }

    ImageView classImage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.classImage);
    TextView classTitlePref = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.classTitlePref);
    TextView classTitle = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.classTitle);
    TextView classTeacher = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.classTeacher);

    if( activity.getIsAccomplished() == 1 ) {
        Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.list_expandable_circle_checked).into(classImage);
    }else {
        Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.list_expandable_circle).into(classImage);
    }

    classTitlePref.setText(activity.getTitlePref());
    classTitle.setText(activity.getTitle());
    classTeacher.setText(activity.getTeacher());
    return view;
}
@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
}
```

Dentro de volley siempre retorna la cantidad exacta de bloques, pero dentro del oncreate siempre es 0.

Alguna ayuda ?

Comment: acabo de ver que usas  listAdapter.getGroupCount() para contar el numero de grupos, pero debes revisar que listDataHeader en realidad tenga elementos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro del **onResponse** de volley, los datos se llenan correctamente. Pero fuera de este no se puede acceder, por que no sabe "que se lleno".

Así que se me ocurrio hacer algo que vi cuando empece a programar en android y quedo asi:

```
//InitData
    initData(new VolleyCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(HashMap<String,List<Activity>> lHash, List<String> lDataHeader)
        {
            listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),lDataHeader,lHash);
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listViewMyCoursesBlocks.setAdapter(listAdapter);

            if( listAdapter.getGroupCount() == 1 ){
                listViewMyCoursesBlocks.expandGroup(0);
            }
        }
    });
```

Eso es lo que modifique, agregue el parametro en la función y una vez se llenan los elementos los devuelvo así:

```
public void initData(final VolleyCallback callback)
{
    final List<String> listDataHeader  = new ArrayList<>();
    final HashMap<String,List<Activity>> listHash = new HashMap<>();

    final String url   = Globals.APIACTIVIDADES_URL;
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.getInstance(this).getRequestQueue();
    StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response)
        {
            try
            {
                JSONObject JSONresponse = new JSONObject(response);
                if ( !JSONresponse.has("error") )
                {
                    int actividadesArr_length = 0;
                    int bloquesActividadesArr_length = 0;
                    int bloquesArr_length = 0;

                    if ( JSONresponse.has("actividades") && JSONresponse.get("actividades") instanceof JSONArray )
                    {
                        JSONArray actividadesArr = JSONresponse.getJSONArray("actividades");
                        actividadesArr_length = actividadesArr.length();

                        listDataHeader.add("BLOQUE I");

                        List<Activity> actividades = new ArrayList<>();

                        for (int i = 0; i < actividadesArr_length; i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject activity = new JSONObject(actividadesArr.getString(i));
                            Integer id   = activity.getInt("id");
                            String title = activity.getString("titulo");
                            String titlePref = activity.getString("tituloprefijo");
                            String teacher = activity.getString("expositores");
                            Integer isAccomplished = activity.getInt("cumplida");
                            Integer isBlocked = activity.getInt("bloqueo");
                            Integer hvVideo = activity.getInt("tienevideo");

                            actividades.add(new Activity(id, titlePref, title, teacher, isAccomplished, isBlocked, hvVideo));
                        }
                        listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(0),actividades);
                    }
                    if ( JSONresponse.has("bloques") && JSONresponse.get("bloques") instanceof JSONArray )
                    {
                        JSONArray bloquesArr = JSONresponse.getJSONArray("bloques");
                        bloquesArr_length = bloquesArr.length();

                        int ini = 0;
                        if( actividadesArr_length > 0 ){
                            ini = 1;
                        }

                        int romanNumber = 1;
                        for (int i = ini; i < bloquesArr_length; i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject bloque = new JSONObject(bloquesArr.getString(i));
                            String titulo_bloque  = bloque.getString("titulo");

                            listDataHeader.add("BLOQUE " + RomanNumerals.toRoman(romanNumber) + ": " + titulo_bloque);

                            List<Activity> actividades = new ArrayList<>();

                            if (bloque.has("actividades") && bloque.get("actividades") instanceof JSONArray)
                            {
                                JSONArray actividadesArr = bloque.getJSONArray("actividades");
                                bloquesActividadesArr_length = actividadesArr.length();

                                for (int j = 0; j < bloquesActividadesArr_length; j++)
                                {
                                    JSONObject activity = new JSONObject(actividadesArr.getString(j));

                                    Integer id   = activity.getInt("id");
                                    String title = activity.getString("titulo");
                                    String titlePref = activity.getString("tituloprefijo");
                                    String teacher = activity.getString("expositores");
                                    Integer isAccomplished = activity.getInt("cumplida");
                                    Integer isBlocked = activity.getInt("bloqueo");
                                    Integer hvVideo = activity.getInt("tienevideo");

                                    actividades.add(new Activity(id, titlePref, title, teacher, isAccomplished, isBlocked, hvVideo));
                                } //for actividades
                            }
                            romanNumber++;
                            listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(i),actividades);
                        } // for bloques
                    }
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "size: " + listAdapter.getGroupCount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //-> here always show correct value
                }
                else
                {
                    JSONObject error = JSONresponse.getJSONObject("error");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: [" + error.getString("num") + "] " + error.getString("msg"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error al recuperar sus datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            callback.onResponse(listHash, listDataHeader);
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
        {
            String message = "Error de conexión";
            if (!error.getMessage().isEmpty()) {
                message += ": [" + error.getMessage() + "]";
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            HashMap<String, String> user = sesion.getUserDetails();

            // get user data from session
            params.put("sesion", user.get(sesion.getKEY_CODE()));
            params.put("curso", myCourse.getId().toString());
            return checkParams(params);
        }
    };
    queue.add(req);
}

private static class VolleyCallback
{
    void onResponse(HashMap<String,List<Activity>> listHash, List<String> listDataHeader) {

    }
}
```

con **callback.onResponse** devuelvo los datos y puedo acceder a todas las funciones del adapter sin ningún error. Nose si será la mejor manera, pero funciona correctamente.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El método que determina la cantidad de grupos dentro del `ExpandableListView` es `getGroupCount()` dentro del `Adapter` que en tu caso es `ExpandableListAdapter` :

```
@Override
public int getGroupCount() { 
   return listDataHeader.size(); 
}
```

en `onResponse()` de tu implementación Volley veo que en el código según ciertas consideraciones agrega elementos a `listDataHeader`, asegura que al final en realidad contenga elementos, esto antes de instanciar el Adapter:

```
  listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),listDataHeader,listHash);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: @Makeyourmove No se estaba llenando correctamente listDataHeader?

Comment: Si, pero no podía acceder a el dentro del onResponse de volley. Deje una nueva respuesta con la explicación.